# How can I change the edge line color when using the 'fill' function in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, fill

When using the filling function in Mathematica, I would like to change the style of the edge line in a way that it has
a) the same color like the filling/no edge line
**b)it will be below/covered by another curve that frames the filling as an edge line**.

Current code for the filling is as follows:

```
fill1 = Plot[{demand1[t1], demand1[t34]}, {t1, 0, t34}, 
Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
FillingStyle -> Directive[LightGray]];
```

EDIT: I have adjusted my second question (now marked bold) since it was not clear in the first version and inserted a screenshot with the "remaining" problem
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the Cos & Sin lines are coloured the same as the filling, and they lie below another line, if that's what you mean by 'borderline'.

```
Show[Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[LightGray], PlotStyle -> LightGray],
 Plot[Sech[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Thanks for the accept.  Here's a fuller answer, following your edit:

```
Show[Plot[{Sech[x],
   If[Sech[x] > 0.8, 0.8],
   If[Sech[x] > 0.5, 0.5],
   If[Sech[x] > 0.3, 0.3],
   If[0.5 > Sech[x] > 0.3, Sech[x]]},
  {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {4}, 4 -> {5}},
  FillingStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> LightGray],
 Plot[Sech[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Gray],
 Plot[If[0.3 > Sech[x], Sech[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Black}]],
 Plot[If[0.8 > Sech[x] > 0.5, Sech[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Black}]],
 Map[Graphics[Style[Line[{
       {ArcSech[#], 0}, {ArcSech[#], #}}],
     Thick, Dashed, Antialiasing -> False]] &,
  {0.8, 0.5, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i have adjusted the question. first part was exactly what i asked for

Comment: OK, understood. It is the order within "show" which defines which lies below what